# Capture desktop audio on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I want to do an audio visualisation with the Raspberry Pi. I already have a python script that uses the alsaaudio library. It captures the sound output and analyzes it.It works on my Linux Desktop Computer, but on the Raspberry Pi i get a error.

```
inPCM = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE)
```

alsaaudio. ALSAAudioError: No such file or directory

I already read that the Raspberry Pi has no capture device. So is there any possibility to capture the sound output?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than switching to PulseAudio and connecting to the monitor?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I found this example [link](http://freshfoo.com/blog/pulseaudio_monitoring), but I can't figure out how to get the values of the different frequencies. Any Idea?